# Is `~#` a tilde expansion of bash?

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

Is `~#` a tilde expansion of bash? I don't find it in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html. My question is from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506532/674. Thanks.

```
$ ~#
The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
  #1 x11 (t4 r3 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's a special escape code of `ssh` that lists forwarded connections.  You are obviously connected to your shell over an SSH connection.

`bash` itself will respond with a "command not found" if you type `~#` on the command line:

```
$ ~#
bash: ~#: command not found
```

Note that to type an `~` *into the shell* as the first character after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will have to press <kbd>~</kbd> twice if your shell is on the other side of an SSH connection, just because of these escape codes.

Other commands that are available are listed in [the `ssh` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS) (these need to be entered as the first characters after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
 ~.      Disconnect.

 ~^Z     Background ssh.

 ~#      List forwarded connections.

 ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded connection /
         X11 sessions to terminate.

 ~?      Display a list of escape characters.

 ~B      Send a BREAK to the remote system (only useful if the peer
         supports it).

 ~C      Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port
         forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see above).  It also
         allows the cancellation of existing port-forwardings with
         -KL[bind_address:]port for local, -KR[bind_address:]port for
         remote and -KD[bind_address:]port for dynamic port-forwardings.
         !command allows the user to execute a local command if the
         PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in ssh_config(5).  Basic
         help is available, using the -h option.

 ~R      Request rekeying of the connection (only useful if the peer
         supports it).

 ~V      Decrease the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written
         to stderr.

 ~v      Increase the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written
         to stderr.
```